# For event.target in onclick - "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')"

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to have my html call a javascript function onclick in which the function itself references the event that called it, but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')
    at play (c:\Users\C2Ran\Desktop\Practice\app.js:5:16)
    at onclick (c:\Users\C2Ran\Desktop\Practice\index.html:24:68)
```

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" defer></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <input type="button" value="X" id="turn" onclick="play(this);">
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
var turn = "X"

function play(event) {
    var cell = event.target;
    cell.value = turn;
    console.log(turn);
    if(turn == "X")
    {
        turn = "O"
    }
    else 
    {
        turn = "X"
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing? Why is it saying `value` is undefined? Is it not getting the event correctly? Or does onclick not count as an event? I also tried `event.currentTarget` instead

Comment: `this` is not the `event` object, it's the event's `currentTarget`. So you can directly do `function play(cell) {  cell.value = ...` (But you'd better avoid `onevent` attributes alltogether, they come with a lot of quirks and are hard to maintain. Use modern event APIs, and the [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes!! This did it, thanks so much! Feel free to put this as an answer and I'll select it haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using function calling in HTML attributes, instead use `addEventListener`,

Your problem is that you are using `this` when you should be using `event.currentTarget`

Note: I've improved a bit your code in `play()` function

```js
function play(cell) {
  cell.value = cell.value === "X" ? "O" : "X"
  console.log(cell.value);
}


document.getElementById('turn').addEventListener('click', e => play(e.currentTarget))
```

```html
<input type="button" value="X" id="turn">
```